# Can't initiate a click on a problematic link

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to initiate a click on a certain link in a webpage. My only intention is to click on that link. I've tried few different ways but I can't get it working.

Link to the webpage: [URL](http://search.wcad.org/Property-Search-Result?searchtext=319%20lizzie%20taylor)

Script I have tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("use_above_url")

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".k-selectable"))).click()
driver.quit()
```

Elements within which the clickable link should lie within:

```
  <div class="k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable">
   <table class="k-selectable" data-role="selectable" role="grid" style="touch-action: none;">
    <colgroup>
     <col style="width:100px"/>
     <col style="width:210px"/>
     <col/>
     <col/>
     <col style="width:120px"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tbody role="rowgroup">
     <tr class="rowHover" data-uid="1fccd732-cd65-4393-b1be-66786fe9ee60" role="row">
      <td role="gridcell">
       R016698
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell">
       R-13-0410-0620-50000
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" style="display:none">
       O0485204
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell">
       GOOCH, PHILIP L
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell">
       319 LIZZIE ST, TAYLOR, TX  76574
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" style="display:none">
       DOAK ADDITION, BLOCK 62, LOT 5
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" style="display:none">
       T541
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" style="display:none">
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" style="display:none">
       S3564 - Doak Addition
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell" style="display:none">
       Real
      </td>
      <td role="gridcell">
       <div style="text-align:right;width:100%">
        $46,785
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
```

If you follow the above url then you can see a line in that webpage containing this exact text `R016698 R-13-0410-0620-50000    GOOCH, PHILIP L 319 LIZZIE ST, TAYLOR, TX 76574`. That is where I wish to click. When you hover your mouse over that link, a shadow is noticed across the link. Hope it is clear what I wanna do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two elements with class `"k-selectable"` on page. The first one is hidden, so waiting for `EC.visibility_of_element_located` will always fail... You need to handle the second one. So just apply more specific selector:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".k-selectable tr[role='row']"))).click()
```

Comment: How to know that there is another class with the same name? Very curious sir. Thanks again.

Comment: `@class` name is not a unique identifier. It used to apply specific style to HTML elements and there might be a lot of elements with the same class names... You can debug with `print(len(driver.find_elements(your_selector)))`. If you get more than `1` in output, then you should apply more specific selector